# Building Outline Data in Google Maps (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm working on an Android project that focuses on knowing how close you are to buildings. I wanted to know if there is some way to extract the geographic information about the outlines of buildings out of the Google Maps API. Thanks.

EDIT: The functionality I'm looking for is similar to what's going on in this app. (Click the link near the top of the page that says "View Live Sample".)

http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/gmaps/help/google_start.htm#topics/samples/identify_features.html

Comment: How did you go with this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wanted to know if there is some way
>   to extract the geographic information
>   about the outlines of buildings out of
>   the Google Maps API.

That information is not available from the Android Google Maps add-on. I have no idea if that information is available by any other means.

Comment: Hmm, It's beginning to look like there are currently no magic databases that contain this type of information just yet. I guess I'll have to acquire data on the relevant buildings myself. Thanks for the reply. :)