# Google maps v3, building shape

Tags: google-maps

Is there any way to auto create marker with shape like building borders by knowing only coordinates, which in this building?

Image example - http://d.pr/eqUT

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. If you know coordinates of all corners of that building, you could draw a ploygon, check this out: http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/googletool.html

also [google maps API v3 - how to draw dynamic polygons/polylines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394961/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-draw-dynamic-polygons-polylines)

Comment: That's the point, i don't know coordinates of ALL corners of that building, i want to know them from google API. I want to work with object building, wich has properties. Not with image with building.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to know those coords and unfortunately they're not available from google maps api, check this for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017074/building-outline-data-in-google-maps-android and everywhere on tinternet.